# Number of unique non-collinear vector with integer elements up to n

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I want to find the number of unique non-collinear vector with integer elements up to $n$ without permutation. $n$ is the largest element in the vector.

For n = 2 you have (ijk):

`100, 110, 111, 210, 211, 221`

122 doesn't work because it is a permutation of 221.

Is there a general formula to find the number of these unique vectors for a given n?

Comment: I think this might be https://oeis.org/A048134 but no formula is given there, which suggests there is no formula.

Comment: Well actually there is the formula $\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{d|k} \mu\left(k/d\right)(d+1)(d+2)/2$ at [oeis.org/A048134](https://oeis.org/A048134).

Comment: @Fabius, true; I assumed OP was asking for a closed-form.

Comment: Any thoughts about the comments, Okano?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, sorry for the late reply, one of my colleague needed that for his thesis (chemistry). He ended up citing the sequence instead of providing a formula (he did check that it was correct up to some n). Thank you to both of you!